# Ajax page loader not working in Chrome and keeps loading after page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code that I have for page Loader which has an issue in Chrome, where it keeps on spinning even after the page is completely loaded.

Below is the script of the function used for the page loader:

```
<script>
function handleStateChange() {
    //alert("Changed"); 
    switch (document.getElementById('MainFrmid').readyState) {
        case "complete":
            toggleLoading(false);
            break;
        case "loading":
        case "interactive":
        case "uninitialized":
            toggleLoading(true);
            break;
        default:
            toggleLoading(false);
            break;
    }
}

function setupLoader() {
    var objIFrame = window.document.getElementById("MainFrmid");
    if (objIFrame.addEventListener) {
        objIFrame.addEventListener('onreadystatechange', handleStateChange, false);
    } else if (objIFrame.attachEvent) {
        objIFrame.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', handleStateChange);
    } else {
        objIFrame.onclose = temp();
    }
}

function toggleLoading(isVisible) {
    objProgress = document.getElementById("divLoading");
    var objIFrame = window.document.getElementById("MainFrmid")
    if (isVisible) {
        objProgress.style.height = objIFrame.height;
        objProgress.style.width = objIFrame.width;
        //objProgress.style.top = objIFrame.style.top;
        //objProgress.style.left = objIFrame.style.left;

        //setTimeout(function () {
            //objIFrame.attr("style", "display:none;");
            //objIFrame.addClass("modal");
            //$('divLoading').append(modal);
            //var loading = $(".loading");
            //loading.show();
            //var top = Math.max(jQuery(window).height() / 2 - objProgress.offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            //var left = Math.max(jQuery(window).width() / 2 - objProgress.offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            //loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
            //objProgress.style.top = top;
            //objProgress.style.left = left;
        //}, 200);
        objProgress.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        //objIFrame.removeClass("modal");
        //objIFrame.attr("style", "display:block;");
        objProgress.style.display = "none";
    }
}
<script/>
```

And below is the table in which I have created a DIV tag for the page loader:

```
<table> 
    <tr>
        <td style="height:81%; width:100%"  valign="top" cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0>

            <iframe  id="MainFrmid" style=" height:521px"  width="100%" height="100%" name="MainFrm" runat="server"  language="javascript"  frameborder="0"  scrolling="yes"></iframe>
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                setupLoader();
            </script>
            <div id="divLoading" align="center" style="width:100pt;height:100pt;   display:none;"">
                <div style="position: fixed; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; overflow: hidden;padding: 0; margin: 0; background-color: #F0F0F0; filter: alpha(opacity=50);opacity: 0.5; z-index: 100000;">
                </div>
                <div style="position: fixed; top: 40%; left: 40%; z-index: 100001; background-color: #FFFFFF; border: 0px solid #000000;background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: center; text-align: center;">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <img src="Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="" />
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Label CssClass="desc_cell" BackColor="Transparent" ID="lblret" runat="server" Text="Loading. Please wait..."></asp:Label>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In all your java script functions please use try/catch blocks which will      
help you in debugging and fixing the issue:

for example:

 function handleStateChange() {
 try{
            //alert("Changed"); 
            switch (document.getElementById('MainFrmid').readyState) {
                case "complete":
                    toggleLoading(false);
                    break;
                case "loading":
                case "interactive":
                case "uninitialized":
                    toggleLoading(true);
                    break;
                default:
                    toggleLoading(false);
                    break;
            }
}
catch(Exception){
alert(Exception.message);}
}
```

### }

In production Environment use:
console.log(Exception.message);

Comment: Yup Thanx vidhyadhar..... done that...pal........but i want solution for my issue............